# Unique cyclic subgroup in dihedral group is characteristic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have seen a proof of "the cyclic subgroup H of dihedral group $D_{n}$ where n>=3 is characteristic". In that proof a result was used.

" H is the unique cyclic subgroup generated by an element of order n,  hence H is characteristic.  " From this how can I say H is characteristic?

I know if a subgroup K is unique of a fixed order n in a group G  then  K is characteristic.  But in dihedral group there are more than one subgroup of order n.
I have not said to prove existence of unique cyclic subgroup in dihedral group.  I said to prove characteristic subgroupness of cyclic subgroup.
Thanks

Comment: In a dihedral group of order $2n$ with $n\ge3$, there is only one **cyclic** subgroup of order $n$.

Comment: Any automorphism maps an element of order $n$ to an element of order $n$.